# Run-time error 429, ActiveX component can't create object, automate MS Word application, CreateObject("Word.Application")

Tags: vba, windows-8, ms-word, ole

I'm running into the following error when executing the following line from VBA (Access):

```
Set wd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
```

[image: Imgur]

I found the following link, but did not find it useful: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828550

### Things I've Tried

---

- Repair installation of Office from Control Panel > Programs and Features
- Uninstall MS Word, re-install
- Tried `Dim wd As Object` instead of `Dim wd as Word.Application`
- Manually run Word.
- Run `winword.exe /RegServer` in Administrator command prompt. Did not run silently, merely opened Word.
- Examine the LocalServer32 key under the CLSID {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}. Initially was missing. After re-install Word, the CLDID was there but LocalServer32 key is missing.
- Run `winword.exe /automation`. Merely starts Word.
- Run `winword.exe` as Administrator.
- Run `access.exe` as Administrator.

### Relevant (maybe)

---

- Windows 8 x64
- Office 2007
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12
- A preview version of Office 2010 was pre-installed.
- Launching Excel works with automation and VBA.
- asycfilt.dll file version: 6.2.9200.16384, date: 7/25/2012 11:05pm
- oleaut32.dll file version: 6.2.9200.16384, date: 7/25/2012 11:06pm
- olepro32.dll missing
- stdole2.tlb no file version, date: 7/25/2012 10:34pm
- McAffee anti-virus

Comment: which way you declared `wd wariable`?

Comment: sorry, now I see that in your question :)

Comment: Can you not use "Set wd = New Word.Application" either?

Comment: What happens if you open up Word first and then run `Set wd = GetObject(, "Word.Application")?

Comment: @CuberChase I have `If [System Level Functions].isAppRunning("word") Then` and it doesn't detect that it is running so still tries `CreateObject()`. It is still failing. Src: http://pastie.org/private/svtooaqmcvox4lhfusqnca

Comment: The code you have is all good.  Unfortunately I think it maybe a system problem and you have taken all the reasonable steps to fix it (short of a reformat!).  I'm sure if you test the code on another computer it will work ok.

Comment: @CuberChase Yes it does work ok with other computers and developers. It's more a MS Word problem.

Comment: @LaymanCoder No, it still fails if I use that line with the same error.

Comment: I have the exact same problem as @Chloe. I am running Office 2007 on 64-bit Windows 7. I forced my code to run by including "on error resume next" and that seemed to make my code work.

Comment: Same problem, but `Set wd = GetObject(, "Word.Application")` works fine for me when word is already running (just testing with `If wd Is Nothing Then`); I can open a document fine from there with `Set wdDoc = wd.Documents(path)`. No luck with any of the above suggestions.

Comment: @Chloe You've probably long reinstalled by now, but do you know if the issue occurs every time you used that code? I only have the issue with `CreateObject` after I've used `GetObject` to check if Word is open.

Answer (score 2):

> Examine the LocalServer32 key under the CLSID {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}. Initially was missing. After re-install Word, the CLDID was there but LocalServer32 key is missing

So Word is unable to register properly because you have a system issue.
As that you've tried most or all of the reasonable steps, your next step is to reinstall Windows.

Or you could try manually registering it by duplicating all the relevant keys from a different machine. But that probably wouldn't solve the problem.

[Super User](https://superuser.com/) might be a better place to ask about installation and Windows registry issues.